# How to draw a box plot in Matplotlib without a dataset?

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to draw box plot from a previous data. I do not have the dataset but I have the median, average, min val, max val, 10th and 90th percentile. I have seen similar questions on here but they all have answers only for 25th and 75th percentile (i.e, 1st and 3rd quartile). Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matplotlib's [`bxp`](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/bxp.html) function could be used. To show the information that is important in your case, instead of drawing the box between the 25<sup>th</sup> and the 75<sup>th</sup> percentile, it could be drawn between the 10<sup>th</sup> and 90<sup>th</sup>. Optionally labels, a legend or an accompanying text could explain the meaning of the elements of the boxplot.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

median = 5
average = 6
min_val = 1
max_val = 9
p10 = 3
p90 = 8
stats = [{'mean': average, 'med': median, 'q1': p10, 'q3': p90, 'whislo': min_val, 'whishi': max_val}]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bxp(stats, showfliers=False, showmeans=True)

names = {'mean': 'average', 'med': 'median', 'q1': 'perc 10', 'q3': 'perc 90', 'whislo': 'min val', 'whishi': 'max val'}
for s in stats[0]:
    ax.text(1.1, stats[0][s], names[s], va='center', ha='left')
plt.xticks([1], ['boxplot 1'])
plt.show()
```

[image: example boxplot]

The following code adds two extra entries to `stats` dictionary for the average plus and minus the standard deviation. These extra entries are ignored by `ax.bxp` and can be plotted in a separate step. As an example, they are plotted with a circular marker.

Note that the plot gets quite full. Also, it might be confusing to add mean and sdev while the five other elements are percentile-based. It can be especially confusing when the sdev would fall outside the rectangular box.

The example shows how 3 different boxplots could look like:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def get_stats(x):
    return {'mean': x.mean(), 'med': np.median(x), 'q1': np.percentile(x, 10), 'q3': np.percentile(x, 90),
            'whislo': x.min(), 'whishi': min(10, x.max()),
            'minus sdev': x.mean() - x2.std(), 'plus sdev': x.mean() + x.std()}

median = 5
average = 6
min_val = 1
max_val = 9
p10 = 3
p90 = 8
sdev = 1.5
stats1 = {'mean': average, 'med': median, 'q1': p10, 'q3': p90, 'whislo': min_val, 'whishi': max_val,
          'minus sdev': average - sdev, 'plus sdev': average + sdev}

x2 = np.random.zipf(2.6, 100)
stats2 = get_stats(x2)

x3 = np.random.normal(np.tile(np.random.uniform(2, 8, 5), 100), 1)
stats3 = get_stats(x3)

stats = [stats1, stats2, stats3]
names = {'mean': 'average', 'med': 'median', 'q1': 'perc 10', 'q3': 'perc 90', 'whislo': 'min val', 'whishi': 'max val',
         'minus sdev': 'minus sdev', 'plus sdev': 'plus sdev'}

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bxp(stats, showfliers=False, showmeans=True)
for i in range(1, len(stats) + 1):
    ax.scatter([i, i], [stats[i - 1]['minus sdev'], stats[i - 1]['plus sdev']], marker='o', color='g')
    if i == 1:  # add explanory texts
        for s in stats[i - 1]:
            ax.text(i + .2, stats[i - 1][s], names[s], va='center', ha='left')

ax.set_xticks(range(1, len(stats) + 1))
ax.set_xticklabels(['imaginary example', 'zipf(2.6)', 'combined gaussians'])
plt.show()
```

[image: adding sdev]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was initially confused if I could substitute 25th and 75th percentile with 10th and 90th but I guess it can be done. I also have standard deviation values. Do you think I could add that info to my box plots? I am very new to matplotlib.Thank you again!

Comment: Thank you very much on your edited answer including standard deviation values. Yes I agree, my plots look busy enough already with the other 5 values. Adding Sd values might not be the wisest thing to do haha. Thank you very much you have helped me alot!